# CastException: after Updating Fragment from ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged

I'm updating my Fragment number 2 using:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    FragmentPage2 f = (FragmentPage2) object;
    if (f != null) {
        f.update();
    }
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
```

Now, when I add and additional and different `Fragment` in `getItem(int position)`, everything seems to be working fine. However, when I run `mPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` it throws me:

```
08-07 19:45:50.844: E/AndroidRuntime(17776): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.foodbuilder.FragmentPage1 cannot be cast to com.foodbuilder.FragmentPage2
08-07 19:45:50.844: E/AndroidRuntime(17776):    at com.foodbuilder.MainActivity$MyAdapter.getItemPosition(MainActivity.java:967)
08-07 19:45:50.844: E/AndroidRuntime(17776):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.dataSetChanged(ViewPager.java:851)
08-07 19:45:50.844: E/AndroidRuntime(17776):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$PagerObserver.onChanged(ViewPager.java:2772)
08-07 19:45:50.844: E/AndroidRuntime(17776):    at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
08-07 19:45:50.844: E/AndroidRuntime(17776):    at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
08-07 19:45:50.844: E/AndroidRuntime(17776):    at com.foodbuilder.MainActivity.onDialogPositiveClick(MainActivity.java:888)
08-07 19:45:50.844: E/AndroidRuntime(17776):    at com.foodbuilder.TablesDialogFragment$2.onClick(TablesDialogFragment.java:57)
08-07 19:45:50.844: E/AndroidRuntime(17776):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
`
```

What is happening? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    if(object != null && object instanceof FragmentPage2){
        FragmentPage2 f = (FragmentPage2) object;
        f.update();        
    }
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}
```

Similarly you can get object class and check if it is assignable from `FragmentPage2.class`:

`if(object.getClass().isAssignalbeFrom(FragmentPage2.class))`

This happens because you have different classes that inherit `Fragment` and `getItemPosition()` does not care about the type of the object, but the casting you do does care about the type of the object.

Hope it helps.